# Android Studio/Intellij hard Wrap (Flutter?)

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, ide

I dont understand how do I change this new line "line" and change the point where the IDE starts a new line when I press STRG+ALT+ENTER. I also tried "Code style -> General -> Hardwrap" but it dosent change anything!
I saw it depends on the Programming langurage I use.... Now I have really no idea how to change this
[image]

Comment: The IDEs for Dart use the highly-opinionated Dart Formatter to formate the code. It is unlikely you'll have any settings you can change that would influence that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be configured in `Settings | Editor | Code Style | Dart > Line length`.